# Split table into new table from each single row

Tags: linux, dataframe, terminal

I have an output file that looks like this

```
head -10 names.txt

AAACCCAAGTGATAAC-1  AAACCCAAGTGATAAC-1
AAACCCACACATTCTT-1  AAACCCACACATTCTT-1
AAACCCACAGTGGCTC-1  AAACCCACAGTGGCTC-1
AAACCCAGTCCCGCAA-1  AAACCCAGTCCCGCAA-1
AAACCCAGTGACTCTA-1  AAACCCAGTGACTCTA-1
AAACCCAGTGGGATTG-1  AAACCCAGTGGGATTG-1
AAACCCAGTTCCAAAC-1  AAACCCAGTTCCAAAC-1
AAACCCATCCATTCGC-1  AAACCCATCCATTCGC-1
AAACCCATCTGTAAGC-1  AAACCCATCTGTAAGC-1
AAACGAAAGAGTCAGC-1  AAACGAAAGAGTCAGC-1
```

I want to split it so that for each row I get a text file that looks like this

```
head AAACCCAAGTGATAAC-1.txt
AAACCCAAGTGATAAC-1  AAACCCAAGTGATAAC-1
```

I then want to run a command in a loop that uses one of those files every time. how can I do that?

```
sinto filterbarcodes -b possorted_genome_bam.bam -c i.txt -p 8
```

what would be the best practice to do it?

Comment: That's what `split` was made for

Comment: Thanks a lot, and is there away to keep the file extension as txt after splitting?

Comment: Yes. Use `--additional-suffix=.txt`.